# Can't start Framework Qwik project

Tags: npm, qwik

I have an issue while creating and starting project. I followed the instructions given here https://qwik.builder.io/docs/getting-started/ and used `npm`, selected Basic App (QwikCity), but when I start the project I'm given the next error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/106oC.png)

Terminal output:

[vite] Internal server error: Failed to load url /src/root_component_vgnegdacmce.js (resolved id: C:/Users/JESUS LOPEZ/Documents/Universidad/Pasantías/qwik-app/src/root_component_vgnegdacmce.js). Does the filnt_vgnegdacmce.js). Does the file exist?
File: /C:/Users/JESUS%20LOPEZ/Documents/Universidad/Pasant%C3%ADas/qwik-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:39304:21
at loadAndTransform (file:///C:/Users/JESUS%20LOPEZ/Documents/Universidad/Pasant%C3%ADas/qwik-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:39304:21)

I'm using Windows 10 and node 18.12.0, I tried with yarn and happened the same. I'm just testing this framework because I was required to create a component library, so I wanted to test the waters with a basic app project and then move on with the component library but even if I select this option, I have a similar error.

This is my repo: [https://github.com/luisamlopez/qwik-app](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/getting-started/) but it's literally just a brand new qwik project (`npm create qwik@latest`) so I haven't touch anything.

Comment: I have cloned your repo and everything is working fine for me .

Comment: whare is `root_component_vgnegdacmce.js` file in your filesystem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine without any problems. Maybe some node modules or other dependencies would have not been installed properly because of firewall or network issues.

Clean the node_modules manually delete the folder or by the following command

```
rm -r node_modules/
npm prune
```

Note: prune command is optional.

Install the package dependencies by

```
npm i
```

Make sure the installation happens successfully without any issues or try to install with a different network or turn off the firewall for a while. Or worst case try with different machines.

Comment: Apparently, there was an issue with my node version, I could run the project creating it on another disk.  Thanks anyways :)